# A series resistor behind a reverse biased zener diode

Tags: resistors, voltage-divider, zener, series

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ff9aCg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If the Zener is rated at 4V, and the resistors R1 R2 are both 300ohm, may I know what is the value for Vout?

I know this is a silly way of regulating voltage, but please temporary put aside the practicality. Does zener diode drop voltage like other individual resistors do - and hence we get something out of Vout node?

Comment: To answer the question you need to specify the value of the top resistor.

Comment: A silly way  to use a Zener, you get no regulation, since any change in the 12V Vin is passed right to V out.

Comment: @Jun You can insert a schematic using a button above the editor, so you don't have to hand-draw them (though the effort is appreciated!).

Comment: This question is meaningless without knowing what the top resistor is, as Russell already pointed out.  It is also meaningless to talk about Vout without saying what it is in reference to.  Voltage is always a *difference* between two nodes.  Your schematic gives no hint as to what the other node is that is the implied 0 reference for Vout.

Comment: This is now the second question you have posted here, and both have been very poorly worded and ambiguous.  For example, what does it mean to have a resistor "behind"?  Behind *what*?  We speak English here.  If you can't communicate effectively in English, then either get someone else to do it for you or don't post here.

Comment: @Olin Lathrop The last part of your last comment was not strictly necessary.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I appreciate your input, your frustration meant much to me. I would like to know whether a zener diode cause voltage drop like a resistor do.

Comment: Finally we have a decent schematic and a clear question.  That took way too long.  Yes the zener will drop 4 V.  It is as if you have a 8 V source driving only the R1/R2 resistor divider.  The voltmeter will therefore read 4 V.

Comment: @OlinLathrop More weird question, if I put the zener "in front of R1" or "behind R2" ,  Vout will still be a 4V?

Comment: Yes, R1 and the zener are in series.  Their order doesn't matter for the purpose of the voltage accross R2.

Comment: @OlinLathrop thanks, I am new here, which button allows me to give you a thumbs up?

Answer (score 3):

Although it's not quite clear from your circuit as drawn, it's likely that \$V_{out}\$ is just the voltage across the \$300\Omega\$ resistor.

If so, and assuming \$V_{ZD} = 4V\$, the output voltage is found simply by voltage division.

Let the value of the top resistor be \$R\$, then

$$V_{out} = \left(12V - 4V\right)\frac{300\Omega}{R + 300\Omega} $$

Answer (score 2):

No, 8V is not correct. Ignore any current that might be flowing out of the node labeled "Vout" and calculate the current through the three components. Now calculate the voltage drop across each one.

BTW, EE.SE has a built-in schematic editor. Just edit your post and hit control-M to bring it up. It will create a schematic that's much easier to read and less ambiguous, and it will label the components so that we can talk about them. It's also a simulator, so you can get your answer that way, too.

Comment: It would also be important to say the zener has an on-state resistance that would help in such calculations. Either that or model the zener as a voltage source and neglect the comparable small resistance.

Answer (score 1):

Using Kirchoff's Voltage Law we find:

$$-V_{SS}+i*R_1 + 4V + i*R_2 = 0$$
$$i = \frac{V_{SS} -4}{R_1 + R_2}$$

Where finally, the voltage at the node of interest is:

$$V = i*R_2 = (V_{SS}-4)*\frac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2}$$

With the known values we can find the solution as:

$$V = \frac{8*300}{R_1 + 300}$$

Depending on the value of the resistor you have before the zener.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Sherrelbc , are you saying that a zener diode (rated at 4V) will drop Voltage in a circuit as if it is a resistor?

Comment: @JunWenTeh, What I mean by the schematic is that the zener diode acts like a battery with the polarity shown when it is conducting in its reverse breakdown region. There *is* a series resistance metric that can be used as well, but it's typically quite small and would make negligible difference in this circuit. Take a look at [this](http://www.ittc.ku.edu/~jstiles/312/handouts/Zener%20Diode%20Models.pdf)